# RTX3060Ti no Signal on TV after restart unless I follow these exact steps

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

I just bought PC with RTX3060Ti card. I connect it to LG 65UJ620V TV which has 3xHDMI 2.0 ports.
There is no signal from both HDMI ports. I had no issues with laptops having GT750 and GTX960 cards.

The only way to get signal is:

1. Have HDMI cable disconnected on the GPU side.
2. Turn on PC
3. Turn on TV
4. Plug the HDMI cable after 20 seconds.
   I have the signal and I can reconnect the cable, switch ports, turn off TV, whatever it will work fine until I restart PC, then I need to shut down the PC and follow steps from 1-4 again.
   I have the newest drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other things to try:

- Use a newer hdmi cable, **really**. Sometimes older cables may not support newer hdmi/hdcp/hdr standards, or it could just have a busted pin that causes weird hdmi handshake issues.
- Update the TV (software) itself.
- Change some display settings in windows, on the TV, or both. For example:

  - set resolution to 1080p/2160p
  - set refresh rate to 60hz/120hz
  - turn on/off HDR
- Does the TV show up as a display in windows, even when showing no signal? Then try waking it by changing the resolution, or setting it to disconnected and back
- Instead of restarting your whole computer, try restarting your graphics drivers: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- Reset your external display settings to force windows to 'rediscover' a particular display device. To do so, delete these three registry keys. **Warning:** this applies to *all* displays:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\ScaleFactors
```

Hope this helps. For people trying to avoid weird hdmi issues, pay attention to the supported hdmi versions of each device. 2.0a, 2.0b, and 2.1 each behave a bit differently. Going up or down version steps can involve some jank, and HDR, and/or 4k+120hz are especially temperamental.

Comment: Removed the regedit entries, restarted graphics drivers, that didn't help. I ordered certified 2.1 HDMI cable and just in case Display Port to HDMI converter. I don't want to update the TV I have it less than 4 years, it's 65" works absolutely fine :(  I don't know if TV is detected in Windows when there is no signal because this is the only monitor I got. I played with resolutions, didn't help.

Comment: Updating WebOS of TV from 3.x.x to 6.0.20 helped, thank you, I originally misunderstood the update TV point.